# What's the standard pattern for a method that might fail for different reasons?

Tags: java, c#, .net

Say I have a method that will post some content online and return true/false representing success/failure.

However, my method can fail at different steps, for example:

- Blocked by spam blocker
- Network error
- Unanticipated exception

I still want the method to simply return a Boolean, I also don't like the idea of letting the method just throw its exception and every caller has to wrap it in a try/catch (I hate try/catch, it's always ugly).

Is there a standard solution for this problem?

The best solution I came up with is to make it return an enum instead with the different possible outcomes, then the caller will have a switch statement. Is there a solution better than this?

EDIT: I should have been more clear; this is an Android app, the user will be posting comments online, the different errors will be translated into messages for the user e.g. "Spam, wait before trying to post again"

Comment: yes, enum would be fine for this purpose.

Comment: `every caller has to wrap it in a try/catch` Even if you throw exceptions, there is no need to wrap everything in a try/catch. You should only catch exception in [appropriate places](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.jp/2009/08/first-rule-of-exception-handling-do-not.html).

Comment: You C# guys crack me up. Java doesn't give you such an option, you must catch every checked exception (or one of that exception's parent classes). Sometimes I envy you. Usually, I weep for you. That blog you just linked to is hysterical.

Comment: @CodyS: Good point, I haven't used Java for a while ;). However, that brings up an issue with this question, the OP needs to choose either `java` or `C#`, not both.

Comment: I definitely agree with that.

Comment: @JesseGood I saw it as a question that's relevant to many different languages in this same family. If I'm using Scala, I would go for case classes and pattern matching without thinking, but in C#/Java, it isn't obvious to me and I'm thinking of enums to replicate Scala's approach (to an extent)

Comment: @Spacemonkey: My 2 cents: By focusing on one language, I feel you have a better chance of getting much more detailed answers. Also, replicating constructs in other languages, while sometimes beneficial can also lead to very poor, convoluted code sometimes because you are not using the language idiomatically.

Comment: @CodyS Actually that blog post is totally correct, and would apply to Java also. Or would you really code catch/throw to every function even though you would only really handle it on higher level? There is the throws keyword for a reason. No need for language wars or being holier than thou.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The blog post was a teardown of checked exceptions. If you think checked exceptions are bad, or are too much work (especially with a modern IDE)...That's just lazy. Checked exceptions are good. If you disagree, that's fine, but let's just say I haven't had a Java application wholesale crash due to a RuntimeException in a very long time. Until we got our (Unchecked by default) Exception handing sorted in C#, that dumb app would crash frequently and for no apparent reason. Checked Exceptions are good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning an `enum` is fine. But if you're going to be calling this from a lot of places, you're going to have the same error-handling code in multiple areas (i.e., the same `switch` statement).

Perhaps one approach is to return a boolean, but encapsulate specific error-handling logic inside an error-handler. So you'd define an interface like so:

```
interface PostErrorHandler {
    void handle(...);
}
```

Then you can have concrete implementations:

```
public class SpamErrorHandler implements PostErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(...) {
        ... //code to deal with spam
    }
}
```

The signature of your method to post would then be:

```
public boolean post(String content, PostErrorHandler handler) {
    ...
}
```

You'd then call `handler.handle(...)` based on the error, from within `post`.

If you still want to communicate the kind of error that happened, you can use the approach you mentioned: return an enum instead of a boolean.

As far as exceptions go, more than ugliness, the main reason that using exceptions here is a bad idea is that it looks like these sorts of errors are expected. If so, you are expecting the caller to deal with them in some fashion and they seem to be part of your business logic. But using exceptions is not the correct way these errors. You typically want to use exceptions only if something unexpected happened. If you must throw an exception, then it is better to have some sort of state-inspection/checking method that checks the input to alert you if the input is bad. In that case you can throw an exception (make it unchecked) because the situation is unexpected, since you expect the caller to have used the state-inspection method *before* calling the method.

Comment: Your answer is great, but I think I should have been clearer. My code is simply an Android app, I will be translating the different errors into messages for the user e.g. "Spam detected, wait before posting again".

Comment: @Spacemonkey If you end up duplicating the error-handling code in multiple places, then the handler approach might work better. But if you're just doing this in one central place, your enum approach is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

An Enum might work, but since your method will "post some content online", perhaps consider using HTTP response codes as a guide.

Without going into great detail about the [multitude of HTTP response codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), know that, for your examples:

- Blocked by spam blocker could be a 403 (Forbidden) or something like that
- Network error could be a 503 (Service Unavailable) perhaps
- Unanticipated exception is pretty much the exact meaning of a 500 error.

You could return an integer from your method. Success would then be defined as the return code mod 100 being less than 4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This method looks like it's part of some service, and you don't want to introduce HTTP concerns at this level. But what you could do is return enums, and then translate those enums into HTTP response codes from a layer that *does* deal with HTTP (from a controller, for example).

Comment: Perhaps. He's asking about what sort of return type his method that will "post some content online" should be...which, to me, sounds like he'll be implementing the HTTP communication (perhaps with a library like Apache HTTP, or perhaps with raw sockets). If he is, my answer is...well, it's an option. If not, you may be correct. He wasn't 100% clear on that though.

Comment: I agree - it depends on how he is using the method. But generally I like to maintain a consistent set of "internal" semantics when working with my services. It's only at places where I interact with an external service that I perform translations.

Comment: I agree with your points too. However, OP readily tells us he isn't a fan of checked exceptions. I doubt he'll then be a fan of constructing complex semantic rules for his code then either. returning an HTTP code from the function allows the caller to do as much or as little checking as it wants...even if the codes can be a bit logically abstract.

Comment: Sure. If this was a simple service, translation would probably be overkill. But if it is part of a larger system, translation would be desirable. But over the years I have experienced that everything starts off as a "simple service", and then before you know it, it is not so "simple" anymore :D. So I try to think ahead. :)

Comment: Hey, to clear things up. I'm posting a comment online on a website like Reddit. The server will tell me if it's blocking it as a spam, sometimes it won't respond and sometimes an error occurs that I didn't think of (e.g. some null parameter).
I'm doing this in an app, so the error that happened need to be translated by the UI into something the user can understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should get over your irrational hatred of try/catch.  It is not true that all callers must wrap the call in try/catch; it can be done judiciously at various levels in code, as needed; for example, only the topmost level of your app need worry about catching "out of memory" or "disk full" exceptions.  Meanwhile the try/catch construct can be used with other keywords (such as `finally`), you will have access to nested exceptions and stack traces, and overall will have a much richer debugging experience.

On the other hand, if you simply want a Boolean, there is a naming pattern in use in the CLR that is very common.  You'd provide two functions that do essentially the same thing.

```
try
{
    string output = MakeSomeFunctionCall(input);
}
catch
{
}
```

...is sometimes supplemented with a partner function that does the same thing but returns a Boolean, e.g.

```
string output;
bool success = TryMakeSomeFunctionCall(input, out output);
```

This gives the caller a choice of using try/catch (if detailed error information is needed) or using the "Try*" method (if detailed error information is not needed).

Use this pattern and it should be clear to others what is going on in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I quite-frankly am of the opinion that "there's a [very good] *reason* why we started 'throwing exceptions' instead of 'using return-codes.'"

The essential problem with the "return-code" approach is that *every* client must, with *every* call, account for and properly handle *every* return code.

... And furthermore, it is obliged to do all-of-this, even when ("as is nearly always the case ...") *nothing went wrong.*

When a library, instead, "throws an exception," the client does not have to *test* to see if the request succeeded.  *("If we're still alive, then it succeeded.")*  The client can now `catch` the *specific* exceptions that it can anticipate, while allowing any un-caught exceptions to "bubble up" to an outer-level handler.

I cordially suggest that there was *wisdom* in that strategy . . .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Great.  "'Exceptions' are .. after all .. *'exceptional!'*"  :-D